# How to set an initial screen that is not shown in drawer component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to show an initial screen when the user logs into my react native app.But i don't want to show the screen on the drawer component as i have used drawer component for other screens from react navigation. When the user goes to different screens from the drawer component,i want to make them come to the previous initial screen on pressing back button.

```js
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Map: {
    screen: Maps,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      header: null
    })
  },
  UpdateProfile: {
    screen: UpdateProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      header: null
    })
  },
  SearchDetails: {
    screen: SearchDetails,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      header: null
    })
  },
})

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen : AppStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: `Map`,
      drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Image source={require('./assets/img/s_logo.png')} style={{height: 24, width: 24}}/>
      )
    })
  },
  Search: {
    screen: SearchScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: `Search by`
    })
  },
  Vendor: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: `Vendor List`,
    })
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: NotificationScreen
  },
  Events: EventsScreen,
  Venue : {
    screen: VenueAvailabilityScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: `Venue Availability`,
    })
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen
  }
}, {
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  contentComponent: customDrawerContentComponent,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoure: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
  drawerWidth: 320,
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#fff',
    inactiveTintColor: '#030303',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#B90066',
    inactiveBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    itemsContainerStyle: {
      marginHorizontal: 10
    },
    itemStyle: {
      height: 40,
      borderRadius: 60,
    },
    activeLabelStyle: {
      fontSize: 20, 
      fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
  }
  })

  const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
    ModalScreen:{
      screen: ModalScreen
    },
    LocationNotification: {
      screen: LocationNotificationScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        header: null
      })
    },
    LoginScreen: { 
      screen : LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        header: null
      })
    },
    SignUpScreen: {
      screen : SignUpScreen,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        header: null
      })
    },
    SignUpStepTwo: {
      screen : SignUpStepTwo,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        header: null
      })
    },
    ForgotPassword: {
      screen: ForgotPassword,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        header: null
      })
    }
   
  })



const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  AuthLoadingScreen: AuthLoadingScreen,
  Auth: AuthStackNavigator,
  App: {
    screen: AppDrawerNavigator
  }
})

const MyAppDrawer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <MyAppDrawer />
  }
```

I want to set the map screen as initial but don't want to show that on drawer. How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't ... at least it's not easy. You need to create a custom contentcomponent yourself and implement the navigation. [Tutorial here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#providing-a-custom-contentcomponent). Another approach is to make your appdrawernavigator ,a child of a stacknavigator with the initial screen

```
const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  AuthLoadingScreen: AuthLoadingScreen,
  Auth: AuthStackNavigator,
  App: MainStackNavigator
})


    //the main stack


const MainStackNavigator= createStackNavigator({
  InitialScreen: {screen: InitialScreen},
  DrawerNav: {screen:AppDrawerNavigator}
},{headerMode: 'none'})
```